# How to download file from database/folder using php

Tags: php, download

File uploaded will be store in database and folder (folder name: uploads).Now I want to know how to create download file from database/folder. I have two file butangDonload.php and download.php. When user click word "donload" the pop up box will appear and save the file.

**butangDonload.php**

```
<?php

    $file = "Bang.png"; //Let say If I put the file name Bang.png
    echo "<a href='download.php?nama=".$file."'>donload</a> ";

?>
```

**download.php**

```
<?php
    $name= $_GET['nama'];
    download($name);

    function download($name) {
        $file = $nama_fail;

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where does `$nama_fail` come from? Why do you never use the value you pass to the `$name` argument of the download function?

Comment: I already change it to $name.

Answer (score 17):

I have changed to your code with little modification will works well.
Here is the code:

butangDonload.php

```
<?php
$file = "logo_ldg.png"; //Let say If I put the file name Bang.png
echo "<a href='download1.php?nama=".$file."'>download</a> ";
?>
```

download.php

```
<?php
$name= $_GET['nama'];

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($name) . "\";");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($name));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile("your_file_path/".$name); //showing the path to the server where the file is to be download
    exit;
?>
```

Here you need to show the path from where the file to be download.
    i.e.  will just give the file name but need to give the file path for reading that file. So, it should be replaced by 
    I have tested by using your code and modifying also will works.

Comment: You can also check the working demo in the link : http://websamplenow.com/29/file_download/

Comment: You can direct download by this `<a href='download1.php?nama="asasa"' download>Download</a>` By simply adding `download` attribute in anchor tag

Answer (score 4):

here is the code to download file with how much % it is downloaded

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$downloadFile = fopen( 'file name here', 'w' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "file link here");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 65536);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'downloadProgress'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $downloadFile );
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

function downloadProgress ($resource, $download_size, $downloaded_size, $upload_size, $uploaded_size) {

    if($download_size!=0){
    $percen= (($downloaded_size/$download_size)*100);
    echo $percen."<br>";

}

}
?>
```

Comment: Not really answer to initial question, but this answers MY question :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use html5 tag to download the image directly

```
<?php
$file = "Bang.png"; //Let say If I put the file name Bang.png
echo "<a href='download.php?nama=".$file."' download>donload</a> ";
?>
```

For more information, check this link
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
butangDonload.php

$file = "Bang.png"; //Let say If I put the file name Bang.png
$_SESSION['name']=$file;
```

Try this,

```
<?php

$name=$_SESSION['name'];
download($name);

function download($name){
$file = $nama_fail;
?>
```

Comment: Try to avoid answers that are just code.  It is more helpful to explain what is going on and how it works.  Thanks for posting and keep working at it.

Comment: Switching to sessions instead of query strings isn't going to help and could break by causing data to be overwritten if the site is being browsed in multiple tabs.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also use the following code:

<?php
$filename = $_GET["nama"];
$contenttype = "application/force-download";
header("Content-Type: " . $contenttype);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\";");
readfile("your file uploaded path".$filename);
exit();
?>
```

Comment: This gives access to every file on the server! It's a massive security hole. And `application/force-download` isn't a registered MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

```
function downloadFiles($dir, $file) {
    header("Content-type: application/force-download");
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $dir . $file . '"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($dir . $file));
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');
    readfile("$dir$file");
}

$dir = "folder_path";

$file = "image_name.jpg";
$download = downloadFiles($dir,$file);
```

Try this way, it is helpful for me.