# downloading from website directory with php

Tags: php, file, download

I have an issue with downloading files with PHP. I think the download.php is not working and I need assistance. when I click download button, instead of downloading the file, it is trying to open it like a page and says it is not available in the server, yet it is there. 
this is the error message

website button

```
<a  href="download.php?id=<?=$results['file'];?>" ><button 
class="btn1">download</button></a>
```

download.php

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $stat=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM complete WHERE id=?");
    $stat->bindParam(1,$id);
    $stat->execute();
    $data = $stat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $file = 'files/'.$data['filename'];

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description:'.$data['description']);
        header('Content-Type:'.$data['type']);
        header('Content-Disposition:'.$data['disposition'].';filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Expires:'.$data['expires']);
        header('Cache-Control:'.$data['cache']);
        header('Pragma:'.$data['pragma']);
        header('Content-Length:'.filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you check the error message? Did you forget to put the real error message in there? Thanks

Comment: `use @readfile($file)` to print any error messages.

Comment: @Kalu The `@` is almost always a bad idea. In fact it HIDES error messages

Comment: `<button>` inside `<a>`??? You could try the HTML5 `download` attribute: `<a href="download.php?id=<?=$results['file'];?>" download>Download</a>`

Comment: Also, you have an real security issue here.. Everyone can download any file by changing the ID in URL.. you should assert that the user who downloads owns the downloaded file too..

Comment: @RiggsFolly you're right. should be the other way.

Comment: @peter :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367104/how-to-download-file-from-database-folder-using-php

Comment: a `button` element will by default try to submit a form, which makes no sense here. If you want to get a link that looks like a button you can just use some basic CSS , in fact [bootstrap.css](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#buttons) has this functionality built in.

Comment: all there solutions are not working. I am trying to implement them and I get the same problem every time. anyone with a code that is sure to work?

Comment: Sorry about that, dont know why I thought you were using MySQLI