# PHP script to download file is downloading itself instead of file

Tags: php, apache

I'm aplying this link in order to develop an easy script to download an Android .apk file. But instead of download file, is downloading itself.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22605604

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$filename = shell_exec('ls /var/www/html/app/*.apk');
$contenttype = "application/force-download";
header("Content-Type: " . $contenttype);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\";");
readfile($filename);
exit();
?>
```

Php.info is rendered correctly by Apache.

Thanks.

Comment: If you read the comment below the example from the question on stack, you see already saying that mime type is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path is not set correctly!

Try to use a real path/filename:

```
 $filename = "/var/www/html/app/nameofyourfile.apk";
```

And also your content-type is not set correctly, try:

```
 Content-type: application/com.android.package-install
```

If these two errors are corrected, it would probably force to download your apk file.

Anyway, this should work ->

```
 <?php 

     $filename = "/var/www/html/app/yourfile.apk";
     $contenttype = "application/com.android.package-install";
     header("Content-Type: " . $contenttype);
     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename); 
     readfile($filename);

 ?>
```

Comment: the internet media type for APKs is `application/com.android.package-install always`, or the generic `application/octet-stream`. `application/apk` is either nonstandard or uncommon.

Comment: Edited the answer.